# Convert a char * [] to a string in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

How can I convert an array of character pointers (ie. an array of strings) into a single string in C?

For example:

```
char * args[MAXLINE/2+1];
char s[MAXLINE] = args; //<-- Pseudo code: How is this accomplished?
```

It must involve taking each string from each indice in args and concatenating them together to get the final string.  But when I tried doing this, I couldn't get strcat to work with a char* array.

Comment: `strcat` is one possible answer, so I'm not sure why it didn't work for you. What did you try?

Comment: Can you give us the code of your attempted use of strcat?

Comment: Where you declare char *args[MAXLINE/2 + 1], it should be something like char *args[NUM_STRINGS], since you are declaring an array of strings. That number has nothing to do do with MAXLINE, which is the number of characters in the combined string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to iterate through your pointers and concatenate them. You'll also want to be very careful not to overflow your target buffer.

A naive implementation that doesn't do bounds checking would look something like this:

```
char *ptr = s; // set ptr to the start of the destination buffer
for (i=0; i<number_of_pointers; i++) {
    char *current_arg = args[i];
    char c;
    while ( (c = *current_arg++) ) {
        // copy each character to the destination buffer until the end of the current string
        *ptr++ = c; 
    }
    *ptr++ = ' '; // or whatever joining character you want
}
*ptr = '\0'; // null terminate
```

You could also loop calls to `strcat` but you'll quickly run into [Schlemiel the Painter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter.27s_algorithm).

Comment: Upd. from 2019: `stpcpy` has been added to the POSIX standard, and maybe C too... This allows looping calls to be much faster.